# SharePoint list in Gallery view does not respect item limit setting

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, json-formatting, view-formatting, gallery-view

I have one quick question for which I am not able to find a solution now. It seems to me, when any SharePoint online list or Microsoft List in Gallery view is used, cards does not respect configured Item limit setting and still displaying all the items (cards) created.

I want to limit them (option "Display items in batches of the specified size") to see some navigation buttons aside/down bellow when more than x items is present. Tried on many different lists this morning no luck at all.

Is there any JSON I can use for that or anybody else facing this and it could be considered like a bug?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `groupProps` to group the group related customization options.

For Example:
[image]

For Reference:

[Gallery layout customizations](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/view-gallery-formatting)

[Group customization syntax reference](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/view-group-formatting)